# Data transfer without SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to transfer some data from 3 spreadsheets (Which I got from another DB) in to DB tables. The three spreadsheets contain feedback data, customer data and person data. When moving I need to map foreign key relationships between the data. Is there any way I can achieve this without the use of SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `openrowset`

We can transfer the data using OPENROWSET. But I dont think we can mark FK relation ship while transferring the data. That you have to do after transfer.

See MSDN link here

[OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276850%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)